Researching Topics for Council on Nicaea
I'm researching a topic for a paper on how the Council of Nicaea in 325 AD shaped ecumenical dialogue as we know it today, particularly from the Second Vatican Council. Any ideas?

The council wasn’t really ecumenical- its purpose was to standardize the Roman-Catholic faith because Constantine feared divisions within Christianity since he had made it the State Religion. It didn’t embrace differences in belief and practice but instead sought to force Christians into uniformity.

Are you looking for academic sources that talk about the council? If so, J.N.D. Kelly's Early Christian Doctrine probably has some interesting stuff to say about it.

@RyanPierceWilliams that comment is unhelpful and implicitly accepts a wrong definition of ecumenism.

@jaredad7 it is helpful: it provides one way that you could approach the research problem; by exploring the contrary perspective that it was not ecumenical. Indeed, the debates and politics and power struggles of the fourth century ultimately led to an irreparable divide between the East and West. I didn’t provide a definition for ecumenism but since you brought it up feel free to define what you mean by the term

@RyanPierceWilliams helpful comment; good point.  For OP to proceed, needs to clearly define "ecumenical".

I fail to see how the eastern-orthodox church perspective can be useful here. They would condemn the 2nd vatican council as just yet another non-ecumenical group of bishops in schism deciding to do stuff.

The answer depends on whether we are talking about ecumenism in the broad sense (dialog among the world's religions) or the narrow sense (dialog between Christian denominations). Since Vatican II, many ecumenists indeed focus on the trinitarian basis of this movement. Here are a few examples from various perspectives:

Is the Nicene Faith the Basis for Ecumenism?

The Trinity and Ecumenical Church Thought

WCC Approves a Trinitarian Basis

Ecumenism a 'spiritual process' rooted in the Trinity, Pope says



Since Traditional Catholic Doctrine has long forbidden any religious interaction with non-Catholics with few exceptions, such as for Evangelization, but has never condoned Catholics' active participation in non-Catholic worship.
This outlined well in this passage from article "Worship with Non-Catholics: Can You Do It?" published on 27 February 2018, https://onepeterfive.com/worship-non-catholics
".. Catholics joining in non-Catholic worship, the constant and uniform testimony of Scripture and Tradition must be maintained: Catholics may never actively participate in non-Catholic worship. This prohibition follows chiefly from the First Commandment in light of the fact that all non-Catholic worship is false, actions standing contrary to right faith and in violation of both natural and divine law. Such acts are therefore objectively disordered, independent of the subjective culpability of those who engage in such worship.
A second, closely connected reason for this discipline is that of making a lie by demonstrating a false religious unity: for a Catholic to join in non-Catholic worship is to manifest a certain unity with that community, contradicting the true unity of the Church. This leads to a third reason of scandal: Catholics who actively engage in false worship give the objective impression that such disordered acts are permissible, even laudable, and in this way endanger right faith (on the part of Catholics) and confirm non-Catholics in their error. A final reason for this prohibition is that it involves an omission of fraternal charity: by engaging in false worship, the Catholic fails in his duty to mercifully instruct the ignorant, admonish the sinner, and share the Gospel."
So, it follows that Vatican II has this Modernist Heresy and others.
So, to answer a form of or related Question, a topic more reflective to Traditional Catholicism containing comparisons between Vatican and Nicene Counsel would compare a disOrdering, unJust, unTrue, dividing, soul murdering, Sickening to Body of Christ, type Counsel like Vatican II, from which Modernist Infiltration of High Church Offices to Betray those Duties and Oaths of that Office as well as the Church, Body of Christ, and all non-Catholics in Need of Salvation through Her. Verses a Unifying Counsel such as Nicene Counsel was.
A well researched & documented processes of betrayals starting from Traditional through to Sick Modernists Usurpation of Catholic Church likely would generally to what has happened to our Once sane Western Institutions, from trustworthy unifying pillars of societies, nations, families, and individual souls, into this deconstruction forces ripping our Nations, societies, families, and souls apart in chaos an insanities (insane as acceptable that; mothers kill our babies in silent screaming torturous methods, sex as a choice, Sexual Child Abuse in early grade public schools, for example.)
A deconstruction degrading the reality around us all without pause and in an increasing rate into Hell.
Such a topic for research and a paper, if well done, would be significant to the human race world-wide, would it not?

In Dan Fefferman answer, he references oneof  Pope Francis's public statements and it happens to be one of his very numerous scandalous heresies in Traditional Catholic doctrinal teachings that is required by Faith to Believe to be in Union with the Catholic Church. And Ignorance of Doctrines but intending to change and-or add what is needed to be in union with our True Faith cannot apply. Is the Pope Catholic? Most Traditional Catholics ask or believe not, and Sedeprivationism Believe not, and that and most Higher Offices are not occupied by Catholics, but by Modernists intending Harm.

Sadly, it seems that - by my count - 3 Answers of (-1) score, out of 12 Answers to 12 Questions here has somehow blocked my ability to Answer questions. So, the moderators anti-Catholics, and GramerNazis will not have me to kick-around for a while.
